# Update textbox from loop in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I know this questions gets asked a bit (at least from what I found here so far), but I can't really wrap my head around it. Already tried it with the example from msdn but still no succes. Here is what I'm trying to do: I have a USB-Counter connected to a TLL-ruler. I want to read the value constantly in a loop and write the readout to a textbox without blocking the main UI. I know from other questions that I should use Invoke or Backgroundworker, but have not really found an example which I understood and could use to adjust my code accordingly. The code without any modification, to keep it simple, is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace USB_Counter
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("HS_UC.dll", EntryPoint = "HS_UC_Close")] //+further DLL imports (driver for USBCounter)
    public static extern int HS_UC_Close(int CounterNo);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //initialize COunter
    {
        int A = HS_UC_Init(1, 3);
        string B = Convert.ToString(A);
        MessageBox.Show(B); //to check if there is no error
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HS_UC_SetDistCode(1, 20, 40, 4, 0, 0); //set Reference
        HS_UC_SetRefMode(1, 1);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a = 1;
        int A = 0; //variable that takes counter value (the one I want)
        int B = 0; //variable that takes counter status
        do
        {
            HS_UC_GetCounter(1, ref A, ref B);
            decimal C = (Convert.ToDecimal(A) / 100);
            textBox1.Text = "Das ist: " + C;
            textBox1.Update();
        } while (a == 1);
    }
}
```

}

Now this works as intendet, but as mentioned it blocks the main UI thread (obviously). If anyone found a similar question with some helpful tips to get started with this multithreading topic or any helpful tips regarding my question directly, that would be greatly appreciated.
Best regards from Berlin,
Chris

Update: got it working with following attempt:

```
private void Counter_Read()
    {
        int a = 1;
        do
        {
            int A = 0;
            int B = 0;
            HS_UC_GetCounter(1, ref A, ref B);
            decimal C = (Convert.ToDecimal(A) / 100);
            UpdateTextBox(C);
        } while (a == 1);
    }

    public void UpdateTextBox(decimal C)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new Action<decimal>(UpdateTextBox), new object[] { C });
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text = "Das ist: " + C;
        textBox1.Update();

    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(() => Counter_Read());
        t.Start();
    }
```

From that I get a decimal output which i constantly updating and still am able to utilize the other buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

outsource the loop code into a method. Inside the method you will need to use [`BeginInvoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx) to write to the `TextBox`

```
private void DoTheLoop()
{
    int a = 1;
    int A = 0; //variable that takes counter value (the one I want)
    int B = 0; //variable that takes counter status
    do
    {
        HS_UC_GetCounter(1, ref A, ref B);
        decimal C = (Convert.ToDecimal(A) / 100);
        textBox1.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{textBox1.Text = "Das ist: " + C;}));
    } while (a == 1);
}
```

**First version** using a normal [Thread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx):

Create a Thread and start it with the new method when the `button3` is clicked

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(()=>DoTheLoop());
    t.Start();
}
```

This should not block your GUI and the textbox will show the values

**Second Version** using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx):

Create a BackgroundWorker and register the `DoWork` event:

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    worker.DoWork += Worker_DoWork;
}
```

inside the eventhandler call the same method `DoTheLoop()`:

```
private void Worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    DoTheLoop();
}
```

start the worker in the button click event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Same result in the end :)

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply. Sadly does not seem to work if I would implement it like this, at least nothing is showing up in the textbox (with the bwworker) or UI is blocked with the Invoke. But also no exception is thrown, so I will read furhter into to figure out where my mistake is. Again, thanks.

Comment: @ChristophPoser you will not get any exception thrown it the thread version. You have no output to the textbox? even in the first version?

Comment: no sadly not but I just got it working. I'll update the main question with my solution, maybe you could take a look at it in a minute and tell me if thats a viaable option as well.

Comment: @ChristophPoser I am really curious... what does the `HS_UC_GetCounter` method do? May be you need to use invoke on this method too, I don't see the implementation

Comment: Well, the producer of the USB-Counter provided a programm to test it with the counter but in C++ (driver and the programm in C++). So in order to use the Counter in my C# programm I read that I have to import the .DLL files used to communicate with the unit. Havent looked into the .DLL files though. All the commands ( like HS_UC_GetCounter) are explained in the manual, but are preset by the manufatuer.

Comment: @ChristophPoser and with this new method it works ?=!  seems a little complicated, but if it works, good for you. I still wonder why my solution does not work for you. Because I tested this code, I just replaced your call of the `HS_UC_GetCounter` method with a simple count up of `A`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138117/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-christoph-poser).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look a this link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx).

However, a quick tip would be to register a method for the `DoWork` event and then execute the `RunAsynchronously` method.

Comment: A comment about why the downvote would be great, as it can make improve myself in answering questions. Don't you think?

Comment: ah okay thanks you, have not been to that link (found another one but it looked way more unorganized), I'll work my way through it (downvote did not come from me)

Comment: The comment here is useless since updating the UI from a `BackgroundWorker` involves more than just calling `DoWork`.